# Python : How to make the 'end' keyword argument in print function to stop functioning for this purpose

Tags: python

I'm a code newbie so my vocabulary might be way off.
I'm using python 3.6.3 on OS X 10.10.5

I'm trying to make a function that takes a list like this:

```
grid = [[ '.', '0'],
        [ '.', '0'],
        [ '.', '0']]
```

and print out :

```
...
000
```

Here's my code:

```
grid = [['.', '0'],
        ['.', '0'],
        ['.', '0']]

def spam(eggs):
    for i in range(len(eggs)):
         print(eggs[i][0], end='')
    for i in range(len(eggs)):
         print(eggs[i][1], end='')

spam(grid)
```

I thought that the result would be

```
...
000
```

because print(eggs[i][0], end='') print ... in line 1
and print(eggs[i][1], end='') print 000 in line 2.

But the actual result is

```
...000
```

I think its because the keyword argument end='' is still at work when the execution is going for print(eggs[i][1], end='') after printing print(eggs[i][0], end='').

The problem is that I don't know how to make the keyword argument end='' in print(eggs[i][0], end='') effect to dissappear after

```
...
```

was printed. How do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just print nothing.

```
for ...:
  print(..., end='')
print()
for ...:
  print(..., end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
print("".join([x[0] for x in grid]))
print("".join([x[1] for x in grid]))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
...
000
```